# Adding personalization attributes in MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud

When creating a message in MobileConnect, how do we add/modify the fields in the personalization dropdown?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How to create attributes:

1. In the Data Designer tab in Contact Builder (the default tab when you open Contact Builder)
2. Click MobileConnect Data
3. Click `+ Create Attribute` at the bottom of the MobileConnect Demographics table (here you can find all values available in the dropdown that you have shown).

In case you would be wondering how to fill the attributes with your data - you need to create an Import Definition:

1. Go to the Imports tab in Contact Builder and click Create
2. Select that you want to "Import into a List"
3. In the next step select your source (like a data extension) and "All Contacts - Mobile" as the Destination List
4. Configure steps int he next steps and confirm that you give the customers options to unsubscribe if you do
5. Save the import definition and add it to automation - your import definition will be available under the "Import Mobile Contacts" activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an attribute in Contact Builder > Data Designer > MobileConnect Data > MobileConnect Demogrphics.

And then, you need to map something to this field when importing contacts to MobileConnect in Contact Builder > Imports.