# How to get contact key in MobileConnect SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

I try to get contact key or subscriberkey (the same in Sales Cloud) within a query for contact in MobileConnect but there is no DATAVIEW that contains these key related to the sms tracking view.

Is there any idea to get the contact key for mobile contact?

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct way, but you could work around this limitation by creating an extra attribute that would store your subscriber key:

1. Add it to the Mobile Demographics table
2. Configure the mapping on your mobile import to send your unique ID to the contact key and this new clone attribute

After that you will be able to extract the information with a query to the [Mobile Demographics (_MobileAddress) data view](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/accessing-mobileaddress-and-mobilesubscription-data-extensions).

Comment: Hello thanks for this idea, but this will also map the contact key for the exsting records? and where can i configure the mapping for mobile import?

Comment: Yes, the new value will be added to existing records, but you need to make sure you map the same column as the subscriber key as you used when you were sending to those customers.

I actually described the process of creating and filling an attribute here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253791/adding-personalization-attributes-in-mobileconnect/253807#253807